# MissingMethodException while method is visible in Object Browser

Tags: .net, exception, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, assemblies

I get this error:

[image]

`Aef` is a custom external (shared) library and `IObjectBuilder` is what handles IoC using CastleWindsor.

The weird thing is that when I look at that `Aef` library in `Object Browser`, That method is plainly visible.

[image]

I've done a clean+rebuild of the Aef solution and readded the library, but no difference.

Also, this is code that has worked before. It just seems to have decided to suddenly fail.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

I use a reference folder outside the current solution to which all custom libraries are moved. Somehow many of the references seem to have moved from there to using the one in the bin/debug folders, which is *not* what I want.

> ***What the above update describes is indeed the cause of the issue.*** As the references were changed to the bin folder, I was no longer working on
>   the most recent version of the dependencies. What could cause these
>   changes to the references (they surely weren't done manually)?

Answer (score 2):

Your exception says you are calling a function that receives a `string`, `Object[]` and `Boolean`.
However in the `Object Browser` the function shows it gets only 2 parameters.

Might that be the problem?

Maybe you have an old version of a DLL somewhere? See that the latest assemblies are deployed and no duplicated older assemblies are hiding in certain folders. Delete every built item and rebuild/redeploy the entire solution.

And also check - maybe the old dll is registered to the GAC..

Comment: Ah yes, I overlooked the boolean, that's a good catch. I'll look into it.

Comment: @Spikee - sorry but didn't understand the additional question... :(

Comment: Reworded, hope that helps.

Comment: @Spikee - not completely sure why it changed.. happened to me in the past too.. maybe changes in the proj properties or something. But I always  just try to avid the "Third Party" type of dictionaries that contain other libraries - in most cases I found them to be in NuGet or else I set them to always be copied to the bin\debug

Comment: @Spikee - wanna chat to try and figure it out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117413/discussion-between-gilad-green-and-spikee).